# ado.net query removes file exention when adding string filename to the database

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dataset

I am using the code below for saving uploaded picture and makigna thumbnail but it saves a filename without the extension to the database, therefore, I get broken links. How can I stop a strongly typed dataset and dataadapter to stop removing the file extension? my nvarchar field has nvarchar(max) so problem is not string length.

I realized my problem was the maxsize in the dataset column, not sql statement parameter, so I fixed it. You may vote to close on this question.

```
hasTableAdapters.has_actorTableAdapter adp1 = new hasTableAdapters.has_actorTableAdapter(); 
            if (Convert.ToInt16(adp1.UsernameExists(username.Text)) == 0)
            {
                adp1.Register(username.Text, password.Text, 
                    ishairdresser.Checked, city.Text, address.Text);

                string originalfilename = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\pictures\\" + actorimage.PostedFile.FileName;
                string originalrelative = "\\pictures\\" + actorimage.FileName;
                actorimage.SaveAs(originalfilename);
                string thumbfilename = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\pictures\\t_" + actorimage.PostedFile.FileName;
                string thumbrelative = "\\pictures\\t_" + actorimage.FileName;
                Bitmap original = new Bitmap(originalfilename);
                Bitmap thumb=(Bitmap)original.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, 
                    new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
                    IntPtr.Zero);
                thumb=(Bitmap)original.Clone(
                    new Rectangle(new Point(original.Width/2,original.Height/2), new Size(100,100)),
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
                /*
                  bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,bmpImage.PixelFormat);
                 */
                thumb.Save(thumbfilename);
                adp1.UpdatePicture(originalrelative, thumbrelative, username.Text);
                LoginActor();
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is you are using [HttpPostedFile.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename.aspx) property, which returns fully-qualified file name on the client. So, this code `string originalfilename = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\pictures\\" + actorimage.PostedFile.FileName;` generates something like this:

> c:\inetpub\pictures\c:\Users\Username\Pictures\image1.jpg

Use [FileUpload.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property everywhere and you will probably get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get Image or file extension :

```
string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload.FileName);
```